Chaining I2S with alsa
For one of the projects that I’m following for my job I’m supposed to define the device tree of a custom embedded board.
The problem is that the audio stream for the board is structured as follows:

cpu to codec via I2S
Codec to ampli via I2S

So we have a chain of I2S stream for the audio reproduction.
My aim is to have this i2s stream works when I execute a simple speaker test on the sound card, which is composed by those two elements.
How can I configure the sound node for the device tree?
I’ve looked around the web to found some solution, but I didn’t found anything.
Can you guys give me some advice?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

hi! I can't really put my finger on what your question is…

@MarcusMüller you're rigth, it was bit confusing. I just edited it! Hopefully, now the question is a bit more clear

@MCT thanks! yes that helps. I must admit, though, that I'm not sure how (and whether) to represent I2S connections via DT. What you will want to have is that the I2S component inside the CPU is correctly used – however that is connected internally. That might be a job for DT

@MarcusMüller the stream from the CPU to the codec is working already. Is the "forwarding" the problem.

but usually I2S devices are just connected to their sources, directly; there's nothing to "forward" when the connection is literally just a conductive trace? There's nowhere else the signal could end up.

That's true, but my configuration is a bit different:

the cpu is the one that sends the audio stream via i2s
then the signal arrives to a codec
the codec processes it and sends it to an ampllifier via i2s (it is another port)

